# Internet shortcuts open Print dialog

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox, shortcuts

I use Firefox as default browser.

Problem: Double-clicking on any internet shortcut in Explorer opens the Print dialog.

Setting for .url under Set Associations is "Internet Browser, Microsoft Corporation".

If I change that setting to Firefox, double-clicking a shortcut gives this error:

[image: http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/9363/screenshot2013042610313.png]

What is the correct setting to use here? And what may the cause and solution of this problem?

EDIT:

Top **bold** right-click option in Explorer is Print. So probably this is a registry problem. Regedit shows the following, where I think something must be wrong?

Shouldn't there be a DefaultAction and OpenWithProgids?

[image: http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/6664/screenshot2013042611375.png]

EDIT 2:

Here is the full registry entry. Though I don't know how to reset it, or what to manually change?

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.URL] @="InternetShortcut"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.URL\PersistentHandler] @="{8CD34779-9F10-4f9b-ADFB-B3FAEABDAB5A}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.URL\ShellEx]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.URL\ShellEx\{000214EE-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}] @="{FBF23B40-E3F0-101B-8488-00AA003E56F8}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.URL\ShellEx\{000214F9-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}] @="{FBF23B40-E3F0-101B-8488-00AA003E56F8}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.URL\ShellEx\{00021500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}] @="{FBF23B40-E3F0-101B-8488-00AA003E56F8}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.URL\ShellEx\{CABB0DA0-DA57-11CF-9974-0020AFD79762}] @="{FBF23B40-E3F0-101B-8488-00AA003E56F8}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.URL\ShellEx\{FBF23B80-E3F0-101B-8488-00AA003E56F8}] @="{FBF23B40-E3F0-101B-8488-00AA003E56F8}"
```

EDIT 3:

Not sure if I'm correct, but I assume .url reg-entry forwards to InternetShortcut? So I post that here:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut] "NeverShowExt"="" "InfoTip"="prop:System.Link.TargetUrl;System.Rating;System.Link.Description;System.Link.Comment" "EditFlags"=dword:00000002 "FullDetails"="prop:System.Link.TargetUrl;System.Rating;System.Link.Description;System.Link.Comment" "IsShortcut"="" "FriendlyTypeName"="@C:\\Windows\\System32\\ieframe.dll,-10046" "PreviewDetails"="prop:System.Link.TargetUrl;System.Rating;System.History.VisitCount;System.History.DateChanged;System.Link.DateVisited;System.Link.Description;System.Link.Comment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut\CLSID] @="{FBF23B40-E3F0-101B-8488-00AA003E56F8}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut\DefaultIcon] @="C:\\Windows\\System32\\url.dll,5"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut\shell] "CLSID"="{FBF23B40-E3F0-101B-8488-00AA003E56F8}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut\shell\Open] "LegacyDisable"="" "CLSID"="{FBF23B40-E3F0-101B-8488-00AA003E56F8}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut\shell\Open\Command] @="rundll32.exe ieframe.dll,OpenURL %l"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut\shell\print]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut\shell\print\command] @="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\rundll32.exe\" \"C:\\Windows\\System32\\mshtml.dll\",PrintHTML \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut\shell\printto]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut\shell\printto\command] @="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\rundll32.exe\" \"C:\\Windows\\System32\\mshtml.dll\",PrintHTML \"%1\" \"%2\" \"%3\" \"%4\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut\ShellEx]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseSVN] @="{30351349-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\{FBF23B40-E3F0-101B-8488-00AA003E56F8}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut\ShellEx\IconHandler] @="{FBF23B40-E3F0-101B-8488-00AA003E56F8}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers\{FBF23B40-E3F0-101B-8488-00AA003E56F8}]
```

EDIT 4:

After running ccleaner (fixing all registry issues) and executed "Set this program as default" for Firefox (under "Set your default programs"), the URL links opens fine in Firefox, as long as that is the default for .URL. However if setting "Internet Browser MS" as default for URL, it still opens Print dialog. And context menus looks like this respectively:

Firefox as default for .URL:
[image]

"Internet Browser" (note: not IE) as default for .URL:
[image]

Though, if using Internet Explorer as default, it works well:
[image]

Perhaps I just should never use "Internet Browser"? Though I would expect that to just direct to the default browser?

Comment: Are you opening .png files

Comment: No these are `.url`, to normal web addresses.

Comment: What is the FF version?

Comment: @Buscar웃 `20.0.1`, but I've had this problem for a long time. Updated recently directly from 13 (I believe) to 20, and had this issue also with 13.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the default action for url is `Print`. That's the top **bold** option when I right-click an url in `Explorer`

Comment: I assume you tried to change that in file associations.

Comment: @Buscar웃 You mean the `default action`?  I see no way to change that there. Isn't that different from `default program` ?

Comment: Your assumption is correct, and you are welcome :)

Comment: So you're having this issue only if .URLs are associated with Internet Browser MS? You say it's not IE so WTH is this program anyway? Can you run it somehow and post a screenshot/version info? Are you sure it's not malware of some kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the Internet Explorer set as default.

And its associations and its defaults.

To change that to Firefox lets do following:

File association

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Change-which-programs-Windows-uses-by-default

Choose Firefox as browser.

Assign the following protocols and file types to the browser you wish to set as default:

URL:HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP protocol)

URL:HyperText Transfer Protocol with Privacy (HTTPS protocol)

URL:File Transfer Protocol {FTP protocol)

HTML File

Comment: what is this ? [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut\shell\print\command] @="\"C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe\" \"C:\Windows\System32\mshtml.dll\",PrintHTML \"%1\""

Comment: Foregive me if I'm wrong, but how is this different from changing specific association for `.url` which I tried according to original post?  I tried change that to Firefox, it gave a popup error, although different from when IExplorer is default. But either program should work as default I presume? And neither does.

Comment: I can't answer what that reg entry is. I'm not qualified. This is where I need help. But maybe you didn't ask *me*..

Comment: All I can say at this point is: It looks like you have some leftovers in your registry. Clean it with reg Cleaner then follow my advice above.

Comment: Ok, you mean like with ccleaner?

Comment: Well, thanks! that process helped, though all still seems not quite right. I added an EDIT 4 above.

Comment: You are welcome, if we are done, please close this question.

Comment: Sure, would just be good to understand if this is expected behavior when `Internet Browser` is set as .URL default, or if I still have a registry issue? It doesn't really seem natural..

Comment: No it is not expected for IE, your IE had that kind of settings. I do not know why.

Comment: Well it's not IE, it's Internet Browser, which still shows this behavior.

Comment: Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat? Or if you like start a new question, since this one is solved.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8501/discussion-between-bretddog-and-buscar-)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend deleting and replacing the internet shortcut.

You can create a shortcut by right clicking on the desktop and select Shortcut.

the shortcut can either be a link or access to another program

Comment: It's not one shortcut, it's *any* shortcut. (Edited that from *an* to *any*, if that was confusing)

Answer (score 0):

This script from Autohotkey seems to solve it directly by repointing where the default browser is (assuming it's portable, I think, but it may do [Autohotkey Script](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/89803-set-default-browser-in-registry-correctly-handles-url-files/)

Answer (score 0):

Type regedit in the Run prompt (Win +R) and press the Enter key. Once the Registry Editor opens, navigate to-
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\

Right-click on *Classes*, and create a New KEY with the name *InternetShortcut*

Right-click on the *InternetShortcut* folder and create a folder *shell*

Right-click on the *shell* folder, and create a folder *Open with…*

In the *Open with…* folder, right-click on the right-panel and then create a new string with the name *ExplorerCommandHandler*

Double-click *ExplorerCommandHandler* to edit it, and add the following in the value section:

`{4ce6767d-e09b-45dc-831d-20c8b4ea9a26}`

Once done, close the Registry editor, and right-click on the InternetShortcut file or the .URL file.

Comment: This was what worked for me in Windows 10.