# Internet shortcut (.url) opens print dialog in Windows 10 and not showing an icon

Tags: windows, windows-10, internet-explorer, shortcuts, file-shortcut

When I drag from browser's (Brave, Chrome, Edge, Firefox) address bar a link to the desktop, it creates a shortcut without an icon, and when opened, it opens up as a Print dialog.

[image]
[image]

Default action of .url file type is Print

[image]
[image]

I have set in the settings, default programs of .url files as 'Internet browser', have cleaned registry, sfc /scannow, 'reset to microsoft recommended defaults', but without any success.

[image]
[image]

FileTypesMan shows this for .url file type:
[image]

Comment: See if this information applies. ["Web Document" tab is missing when you check the properties of a URL file](https://www.winhelponline.com/xp/webdoctab.htm)

Comment: @w32sh didn't work. Web Document tab didn't show up.

Comment: A complete file association report for .URL would be helpful. You can generate it using the [FileTypeDiag](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/filetypediag-dump-file-association-info/) tool. Then upload to GDrive/Pastebin and post us the link.

Comment: @w32sh Here it is - https://pastebin.com/fVftrKVz

Comment: Using the Registry Editor (regedit.exe) can you export these branches and post the contents here?

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Blocked`

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Blocked`

Note: The branches don't exist by default.. would be present only if a 3rd party software added them.

Comment: @w32sh first registry folder in HKEY_CURRENT_USER didn't exist. 2nd one existed, here it is as txt - https://pastebin.com/raw/ZaTF92xz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*via ["Web Document" tab is missing when you check the properties of a URL file](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/internet-shortcuts-open-print-dialog-web-doc-tab-missing/)*

1. Start the Registry Editor and go to:

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Blocked
2. Backup the registry key by exporting it to a .reg file.
3. Then, in the right pane, delete the the value named `{FBF23B40-E3F0-101B-8488-00AA003E56F8}`
4. Exit the Registry Editor.
5. Sometimes, you may need to log off and log back in for the change to take effect.

That should do the trick!

Comment: This worked for me in Windows 11. In Windows 10, I used this: https://superuser.com/questions/588003/internet-shortcuts-open-print-dialog/1726971#1726971

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an issue in the Registry. There are *many* locations, and levels of indirection, for file handling, so attempting to fix this issue by manually editing the Registry might be an option of last resort.

Here are some things to check:

- Is the *Internet Shortcut* properly formed? Look at its *Properties*, and copy-and-paste the URL into a browser. If that's bad, the issue occurs when *creating* the shortcut.

[image: Web Document Properties]

- Right-click on *.URL* in Nirsoft's [FileTypeMan](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html), that you've already used, and confirm the Registry key is `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ie_to_edge_bho.IEToEdgeBHO`. BTW, when I view *.URL* in that tool, I see only a single entry for .URL, with a round, blue icon.

[image: URL Registry Key]

- Compare the Registry settings with those shown in Nirsoft's [.URL Extension](http://extension.nirsoft.net/URL).

If all else fails, try the following:

- Reinstall your browser.
- Be sure you have not removed Windows' default web apps, Edge and the IEtoEdge app. If they've been removed, then download a Windows ISO, and reinstall, keeping files.

Comment: There is no Web Document tab in .url file properties.
And .url in FileTypesMan opens to registry key - "Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut"

Comment: @computeruser1, The answer has been edited to show how the properties of a URL shortcut (link) should look. If your OS doesn't even show the *Web Document* tab, then I'd strongly suggest reinstalling Windows from ISO -- the OS is more damaged than can easily be fixed otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In NirSoft's FileTypeMan, simply remove the checkmark from "Disabled" in the "Edit Action" (=<kbd>F3</kbd>) dialog for the `.url` extension. In your case, the "Open" action seems to be disabled.

Screenshot for "Edit Action":

[image: Screenshot for "Edit Action"]

After that, choose "File/Refresh Desktop Now" (=<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) in the main menu to apply this change.